# How do I make Flutter app open in all devices. Crashing because it couldn't find libflutter.so. How do I fix this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-apk

So after a point of time developing my Flutter application, I find myself where my app is not opening in all architectures. I tried to see if the crash comes to Crashlytics, but understood only when we open our app next time the app will open.

I tried some of the solutions out there to keep `abiFilters` in ndk block of the `build.gradle`. Nothing worked.

yaml dependencies are

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
   sdk: flutter

  http: ^0.13.3
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  flutter_background_geolocation: ^4.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  provider: ^5.0.0
  mixpanel_flutter: ^1.0.0
  swipebuttonflutter: ^1.0.0
  flutter_swipe_button: ^1.1.0
  synchronized: ^3.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^6.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.4.0
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
  path: ^1.8.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.4
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.1.1
  firebase_performance: ^0.7.0+7
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

And the apk structure is [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to run it after keeping all `abiFilters` in defaultConfing and in release blocks in the `build.gradle` file.

The main reason is Flutter is building apk specific to the device that ur system is connected to. We need to close all the device connections and use the command

`flutter build apk --debug` or `--release` for release build